# Can AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient handle native Javascript Date objects?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DocumentClient (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) to make working with DynamoDB easier.  However, it seems like it is having trouble with Date objects.  I know that DynamoDB wants dates formatted specifically `Date (as ISO8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)`.

**Does DocumentClient just not handle this, or is there something that needs to be set on the Date object?**

For now, I've just been converting the value to a string via `toString()`.
The `expires_at` value is the value specifically:

This one does not include `expires_at` in the DyanmoDB Item.

```
{ 
  Item:
  { 
    id: 'session',
    credentials: 
    { 
      access_token: '',
      refresh_token: '',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: 3599,
      expires_at: 2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z 
    } 
  },
  TableName: 'table' 
}
```

And this one will include it:

```
{ 
  Item:
  { 
    id: 'session',
    credentials: 
    { 
      access_token: '',
      refresh_token: '',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: 3599,
      expires_at: 'Mon Apr 17 2017 18:50:24 GMT+0000 (UTC)' 
    } 
  },
  TableName: 'table' 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) is just an abstraction layer for DynamoDB. So, if the `Date` data type is not supported in DynamoDB, it won't be supported in DocumentClient. (See [DynamoDB Data Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes))

What you can do is pass the ISO 8601 string using the [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method. For example:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (60*60*1000)); // Add 1 hour.

{ 
  Item:
  { 
    id: 'session',
    credentials: 
    { 
      access_token: '',
      refresh_token: '',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: 3599,
      expires_at: expires.toISOString() 
    } 
  },
  TableName: 'table' 
}
```